# Cannot read property 'node' of undefined while npm run build

Tags: build, graphql, gatsby

I have the method which gets data from contentful using graphql and returns some data:

```
  exports.getMetadata = async (graphql, reporter, query) => {
  const result = await graphql(query)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild("Error while running medatada GraphQL query")
  }
  
  const {
    data: {
      allContentfulPages: {
        edges: {
          0: {
            node: { meta, opengraph },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  } = result

  const metaJson = JSON.parse(meta.internal.content)
  const opengraphJson = JSON.parse(opengraph.internal.content)

  return { metaJson, opengraphJson }
}
```

that's how graphql query looks:

```
    query {
  # since our Contentful has enabled "locales", but pages slug doesn't need it, get only default language data
  allContentfulPages(filter: { node_locale: { eq: "en-US" }, slug:{eq: "insights"} }) {
    edges {
      node {
        meta {
          internal {
            content
          }
        }
        opengraph {
          internal {
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i start project executing `npm run develop` everything works fine and i don't have any error in console but while building `npm run build` i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined` i tried to add statement like `if result !== null ...` and `if result....edges[0].node !== null` in many variants it didn't work, application all time breaks in one place. Please help me to figure out what;s going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much [unguarded/unconditional] decomposition... stop at must exist node:

```
const { data: { allContentfulPages: { edges }}} = result;
if( edges && edges[0] ) {
  return {
    metaJson: JSON.parse(edges[0].node.meta.internal.content),
    opengraphJson: JSON.parse(edges[0].node.opengraph.internal.content)
  };
```